# Parse http GET and POST parameters from BaseHTTPHandler?

Tags: python, http, basehttpserver

BaseHTTPHandler from the BaseHTTPServer module doesn't seem to provide any convenient way to access http request parameters.  What is the best way to parse the GET parameters from the path, and the POST parameters from the request body?

Right now, I'm using this for GET:

```
def do_GET(self):
    parsed_path = urlparse.urlparse(self.path)
    try:
        params = dict([p.split('=') for p in parsed_path[4].split('&')])
    except:
        params = {}
```

This works for most cases, but I'd like something more robust that handles encodings and cases like empty parameters properly.  Ideally, I'd like something small and standalone, rather than a full web framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/documentation/dev/utils.html#werkzeug.url_decode) modules, the base Werkzeug library isn't too large and if needed you can simply extract this bit of code and you're done.

The `url_decode` method returns a MultiDict and has encoding support :)

As opposed to the `urlparse.parse_qs` method the Werkzeug version takes care of:

- encoding
- multiple values
- sort order

If you have no need for these (or in the case of encoding, use Python 3) than feel free to use the built-in solutions.

Answer (score 89):

You may want to use [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs):

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
>>> url = 'http://example.com/?foo=bar&one=1'
>>> parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)
{'foo': ['bar'], 'one': ['1']}
```

For **Python 2**, the module is named [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) instead of `url.parse`.

Comment: It should be noted that urlparse in Python 2 doesn't handle encodings, the Python 3 version does support that. Additionally, to maintain the correct order `parse_qsl` should be used instead of `parse_qs` which returns a list.

Comment: The module name is `urllib`, not `url`, in Python 3.6

Answer (score 17):

Better solution to an old question (updated):

Python 3:

```
def do_POST(self):
  length = int(self.headers.get('content-length'))
  field_data = self.rfile.read(length)
  fields = parse.parse_qs(str(field_data,"UTF-8"))
```

Working example: [public gist](https://gist.github.com/mscalora/b6f86291353c360cb5550dc978129069)

Python 2.x:

```
def do_POST(self):
    length = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length'))
    field_data = self.rfile.read(length)
    fields = urlparse.parse_qs(field_data)
```

This will pull urlencoded POST data from the document content and parse it a dict with proper urldecoding

Comment: I was trying to make the most basic server that could handle get and post requests in Python, and only yours worked for me in handling POST requests. This was written 3 years ago, but thanks! :)

Comment: This will not work if the POST request uses `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding

Comment: @BalzGuenat BaseHTTPServer implements an HTTP 1.0 server so as I understand it, chunked encodings are not allowed

Comment: In Python 3, this will cause an `AttributeError: 'HTTPMessage' object has no attribute 'getheader'`. To fix, replace the `getheader()` call with `get()`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you investigated using libraries like [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/)?  They provide a much quicker path to handling these things than BaseHTTPServer.

Answer (score 1):

Basic HTTP request parameters support is provided in the [`CGI` module](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#module-cgi).
The recommended mechanism to handle form data is the `cgi.FieldStorage` class.

> To get at submitted form data, it’s best to use the `FieldStorage` class. The other classes defined in this module are provided mostly for backward compatibility. Instantiate it exactly once, without arguments. This reads the form contents from standard input or the environment (depending on the value of various environment variables set according to the CGI standard). Since it may consume standard input, it should be instantiated only once.
>
> The `FieldStorage` instance can be indexed like a Python dictionary. It allows membership testing with the in operator, and also supports the standard dictionary method `keys()` and the built-in function `len()`. Form fields containing empty strings are ignored and do not appear in the dictionary; to keep such values, provide a true value for the optional keep_blank_values keyword parameter when creating the `FieldStorage` instance.
>
> For instance, the following code (which assumes that the Content-Type header and blank line have already been printed) checks that the fields name  and addr are both set to a non-empty string:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
if "name" not in form or "addr" not in form:
    print "<H1>Error</H1>"
    print "Please fill in the name and addr fields."
    return
print "<p>name:", form["name"].value
print "<p>addr:", form["addr"].value
#...further form processing here...
```

Comment: The CGI library doesn't handle encodings (like utf-8) for you so it's less suited than some of the other libraries available.

Comment: Encoding can be delegated to the file-like 1st argument of FieldStorage.

Comment: True, but why bother when there are scripts that handle this for you including the catching of errors? No need to reinvent the wheel.