# Detect if URL contains parameters in GAE

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine, webapp2

I would like to parse the URL upon load to see if it has any parameters. I'm just trying to set up a basic test to see if that's possible. What is the correct regex to send a url like http://example.com/?hiyall to ParamHandler?

```
class ParamHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('parameters detected')


class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('Hello World')



application = webapp2.WSGIApplication ([('/', MainHandler), ('/\?.*', ParamHandler)], debug=True)
```

Comment: Do you mean all the requests that end with hiyall (eg. phiyall) or some get parameter like http://example.com/?hiyall=somevalue.

Comment: I mean anything involving "example.com/?". I think I know how to parse the url but right now I need to know how to get a hold of the url when it has parameters.

Comment: Possibly related to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7168126/1988505

Comment: Can you give me examples of urls you want to parse. The example you gave http://example.com/?hiyall is invalid unless ? is a regular expression. In which case http://example.com/shiyall is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this in `get(self)`:

```
class ParamHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        hyl = self.request.get("hiyall")
        self.response.out.write("hiyall was: " + hyl)
```

Customary official docs link: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass#Request_get

Answer (score 0):

If you're using webapp2, you cannot route requests based on parameters.

But you can create a condition based on `query_string` which can check if parameters exist. Like the following:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.request.query_string:
            self.response.out.write('Has parameters')
        else:
            self.response.out.write('No parameters')



application = webapp2.WSGIApplication ([('/', MainHandler)], debug=True)
```