# BaseHTTPServer, extracting variable from POST single value

Tags: python, bash, post, basehttpserver

I want to know how to get variables form content POSTed with a html form, located on an external server.

I have this code :

**myserver.py**

```
import BaseHTTPServer

HOST_NAME = ''
PORT_NUMBER=8000

postVars = ''

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_POST(s):
        global postVars
        s.send_response(200)
        s.end_headers()
        varLen = int(s.headers['Content-Length'])
        postVars = s.rfile.read(varLen)
        print postVars

server_class = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
httpd = server_class((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER), MyHandler)

try:
    httpd.handle_request()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

print postVars
httpd.server_close()
postVars is valued during the Handler, but not after MyHandler
```

It currently print this on the console

```
user=jhon&domain=domain.com&pass=mypassword
```

I wnat to extract each variable and use them to call a subsequent bash script.

example of what I want to accomplish :

```
import os
value1="user"
value2="domain"
value3="pass"
os.system("./usersprivetes.sh %s %s %s" % (value1,value2,value3))
```

thank for your comment and assistance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse http GET and POST parameters from BaseHTTPHandler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490162/parse-http-get-and-post-parameters-from-basehttphandler)

Comment: So get, I am interested in post, but thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello solved by adding some code, one that only serves me once, after that variables are passed back to no longer function, I think that is the order in which I have

```
#cat server.py
import BaseHTTPServer
import urlparse
import os

HOST_NAME = ''
PORT_NUMBER=8000

postVars = ''

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_POST(s):
        global postVars
        s.send_response(200)
        s.end_headers()
        varLen = int(s.headers['Content-Length'])
        postVars = s.rfile.read(varLen)
        #print postVars

server_class = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
httpd = server_class((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER), MyHandler)

try:
    httpd.handle_request()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

#print postVars

qs = dict( (k, v if len(v)>1 else v[0] )
           for k, v in urlparse.parse_qs(postVars).iteritems() )
#print qs

pase = qs['pass']
dominio = qs['domain']
usuario = qs['user']

os.system("./createuser.sh %s %s %s" % (pass,user,domain))
httpd.serve_forever()
```

thank you
this made the magic

```
qs = dict( (k, v if len(v)>1 else v[0] )
           for k, v in urlparse.parse_qs(postVars).iteritems() )
```