# How does the Python BaseRequestHandler rfile.read() method work?

Tags: python, http, post

I'm sending a text file with a string in a Python script via POST to my server:

```py
fo = open('data.txt','a')
fo.write("hi, this is my testing data")
fo.close()

with open('data.txt', 'rb') as f:
    r = requests.post("http://XXX.XX.X.X", data = {'data.txt':f})
    f.close()
```

And receiving and handling it here in my server handler script, built off an example found online:

```py
def do_POST(self):
    data = self.rfile.read(int(self.headers.getheader('Content-Length')))
    empty = [data]
    with open('processing.txt', 'wb') as file:
        for item in empty:
            file.write("%s\n" % item)
                
    file.close()
    self._set_headers()
    self.wfile.write("<html><body><h1>POST!</h1></body></html>")
```

My question is, how does:

```py
self.rfile.read(int(self.headers.getheader('Content-Length')))
```

take the length of my data (an integer, # of bytes/characters) and read my file? I am confused how it knows what my data contains. What is going on behind the scenes with HTTP?

It outputs `data.txt=hi%2C+this+is+my+testing+data`

to my processing.txt, but I am expecting `"hi this is my testing data"`

I tried but failed to find documentation for what exactly rfile.read() does, and if simply finding that answers my question I'd appreciate it, and I could just delete this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your client code snippet reads contents from the file `data.txt` and makes a POST request to your server with data structured as a key-value pair. The data sent to your server in this case is one key `data.txt` with the corresponding value being the contents of the file.

Your server code snippet reads the *entire* HTTP Request body and dumps it into a file. The key-value pair structured and sent from the client comes in a format that can be decoded by Python's built in library `urlparse`.

Here is a solution that could work:

```
def do_POST(self):
    length = int(self.headers.get('content-length'))
    field_data = self.rfile.read(length)
    fields = urlparse.parse_qs(field_data)
```

This snippet of code was shamefully borrowed from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31363982/705471

If you'd like to extract the contents of your text file back, adding the following line to the above snippet could help:

```
data_file = fields["data.txt"]
```

To learn more about how such information is encoded for the purposes of HTTP, read more at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: I see, I think I understand. Could you clarify what 'rfile' is though? I understand read() is built into Python.

Comment: You can read more about this here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.rfile. Basically, it is a stream containing all contents from the request body. This is usually setup by Python's built-in `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` or one of its derived classes for you to access when your function gets invoked.

Comment: why shameful? you should be unashamed to have properly credited the idea

Comment: In Python 3, this will cause an `AttributeError: 'HTTPMessage' object has no attribute 'getheader'`. To fix, replace the `getheader()` call with `get()`.